# Understanding the JK latch

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, schematics

I am having a hard time understanding how a JK latch turns on for the first time. For example, if we use a JK latch with NOR gates. We have something like this:

[image]

Let's suppose that \$Q\$ and \$J\$ is initially 1. Since \$\bar{Q}\$ is 0 and feeds back into \$J\$, wouldn't the 3-input \$J\$-AND gate immediately go back to 0, or toggle between 0/1 indefinitely? What prevents that? Or does that not matter because the NOR gate is already set and feeding back unto itself?

Comment: see this http://tinyurl.com/yd2nofge

Comment: @jsotola -- thank you. Also I'll start using that circuit simulator now, as I think that's much better than the one I'm using.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's showing a master-slave JK flop, not a latch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Just attempting to understand the OP for now; will update this answer shortly)

Say initially Q=0.
Look at the bottom NOR gate. It's output will change if one of its inputs becomes 1.
Now, apply C=J=1.
Then the AND gate output becomes 1 which makes the NOR gate output become 0.

Your question is: since the NOR gate output changed to 0, this would make the AND gate ouput 0 which would makes the NOR gate output change back to 1 and so on.

Here NOR gate is acting as an inverter with one input tied to 0; AND gate is acting as a buffer. So you have a ring oscillator which keeps toggling forever. Is this your question?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this -- yes, the last part of the answer is what I'm asking. Could you please elaborate on: `Here NOR gate is acting as an inverter with one input tied to 0; AND gate is acting as a buffer.`

Comment: If you tie one input of NOR gate to 0, then the NOR gate becomes a NOT gate for the other input.

Comment: If the other input is 0, the output will be 1. If the other input is 1, the output will be 0. This is NOT gate. Nothing fancy here...

Comment: thank you, very clear explanation.

Comment: Hey glad you figured it out and my answer helped but I don't think I have answered your question fully. You're asking how the latch can function properly if the NOR gate keeps toggling, right?

Comment: Yea, the whole feedback part of the JK latch is a bit tricky for me to understand (the two levels of feedback -- SR or D seems much more intuitive).

Comment: Actually your question is a legitimate concern and it is called `Race around condition in JK latch`. The NOR gate will keep toggling if the input we tied to 0 earlier REMAINS tied to 0 for a long time. Congratulations for figuring this type of problem exists on your own!  I suggest [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trPGhO7MPnw) short video on the same...

Answer (score 0):

The circuit you show for JK doesn't include any kind of a reset, so the Q and Q- outputs could power up in either state. The initial state of the flop isn't determined, and won't be known until at least one clock has occurred with J,K = 0,1 or 1,0.

And as shown, the circuit will oscillate when J and K are both 1. It's pretty much useless as a workable circuit, unless the intent is a gated ring oscillator. Think about it: when all the inputs are 1, then what's left is a pair of inverters connected head-to-tail. That's a ring oscillator.

You can simulate this behavior in Verilog. Here's an online sim that I recommend: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_verilog_online.php

[Or try it here with Falstad](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.634267539816555%2050%205%2050%0Aw%20336%20224%20336%20240%200%0Aw%20336%20160%20336%20176%200%0Aw%20432%20224%20432%20256%200%0Aw%20432%20224%20336%20176%200%0Aw%20432%20144%20432%20176%200%0Aw%20432%20176%20336%20224%200%0AM%20432%20144%20496%20144%200%202.5%0AM%20432%20256%20496%20256%200%202.5%0Ax%20422%20117%20440%20120%204%2024%20Q%0Ax%20424%20305%20442%20308%206%2024%20Q%0Aw%2032%20112%2080%20112%200%0Ax%2030%2047%2042%2050%204%2024%20J%0AR%2064%20336%2032%20336%201%202%20120%202.5%202.5%200%200.5%0Aw%20336%2064%2080%2064%200%0Aw%2080%2064%2080%20128%200%0AL%2032%20256%2032%20224%200%201%20false%205%200%0Ax%2024%20193%2040%20196%204%2024%20K%0Aw%2064%20336%2064%20256%200%0Aw%2064%20256%2080%20256%200%0Aw%2080%20144%2064%20144%200%0Aw%2064%20144%2064%20256%200%0Aw%2032%20288%2032%20256%200%0Aw%2032%20288%2080%20288%200%0Aw%20336%20368%2080%20368%200%0Aw%2080%20368%2080%20272%200%0AL%2032%20112%2032%2080%200%201%20false%205%200%0A150%2080%20128%20160%20128%200%203%200%205%0A150%2080%20272%20160%20272%200%203%200%205%0Aw%20432%20256%20432%20368%200%0Aw%20432%20368%20336%20368%200%0Aw%20336%2064%20432%2064%200%0Aw%20432%2064%20432%20144%200%0A153%20352%20144%20432%20144%200%202%205%205%0A153%20352%20256%20432%20256%200%202%200%205%0Aw%20336%20240%20352%20240%200%0Aw%20336%20160%20352%20160%200%0Aw%20352%20128%20160%20128%200%0Aw%20160%20272%20352%20272%200%0Ao%2025%2064%200%204102%205%200.00009765625%200%202%2025%203%20J%0Ao%2015%2064%200%204102%205%200.00009765625%200%202%2015%203%20K%0Ao%206%2064%200%204102%205%200.00009765625%200%201%20Q%0Ao%2012%2064%200%204102%205%200.00009765625%200%202%2012%203%20clk%0A)